# IE doesn't show :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am styling the `<hr>` element with an pseudo element but Internet Explorer 11 doesn't support it.

This is how it should look like:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/23rsio2.jpg

```
hr { 
    height:1px; 
    background-color:#D1D1D1;
    border:0; margin:30px 90px;
}

hr:after { 
    background:url('../images/hr.png') no-repeat top center; 
    content:""; 
    display:block; 
    height:30px; 
    position:relative; 
    top:-15px; 
}
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: declare a `width` in your `:after`

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas If you need a Fiddle to be able to answer this question, you should consider revising your knowledge.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If you think I asked for an jsFiddle because I wasn't able to answer this question, you should consider revisiting your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psuedo-elements are handled as *children* of the element they are attached do.

```
<hr>
    <psuedo-element-after> image here </psuedo-element-after>
</hr>
```

This is not valid, because `<hr />` doesn't allow children. Therefore, it won't work.

Consider applying the background image to the `<hr />` itself, or use something like a class to do it, like this: `<div class="divider"></div>`

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if this is browser-based then because Chrome does show the after pseudo-element on hr tags, as does Firefox [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/aD47G/)

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol so IE is correct or Firefox have wrongly implemented? AS FF display the image. check the link in FF http://jsbin.com/tivazafi/1/edit.

Comment: Interesting indeed, but contrary to what may be popular belief, Internet Explorer is *correct* in this instance. Chrome and Firefox *should* be refusing the render the psuedoelement.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Could your reaffirm your statement that `::before`/`::after` doesn't apply on void elements with a spec link? Or are you just assuming?

Comment: I tested `hr::after { content: 'Test' }` in Chrome, Firefox and IE11. The pseudo-element is rendered in all these browsers, so it seems that pseudo-elements *are* valid on `<hr>` and other void elements.